# Forms not submitting

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Here FullMaid form and Cleaner form could not be submitted...It is not even entering into the request.POST .Other forms are working and it gets submitted. Only these two forms are not working.
This is the views.py code

```
def staffApply2(request, domestic_works, uid):
    user = User.objects.get(id=uid)
    staff = StaffApplicantTable.objects.get(user=user)
    formsets = []
    if 'cook' in domestic_works:
        formsets.append(CookingForm(request.POST, prefix='cook'))
    if 'driver' in domestic_works:
        formsets.append(DriverForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='driver'))
    if 'nanny' in domestic_works:
        formsets.append(NannyForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='nanny'))
    if 'gardener' in domestic_works:
        formsets.append(GardenerForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='gardener'))
    if 'elder-care-taker' in domestic_works:
        formsets.append(ElderCareTakerForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='elder-care-taker'))
    if 'full-maid' in domestic_works:
        formsets.append(FullMaidForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='full-maid'))
    if 'cleaner' in domestic_works:
        formsets.append(CleanerForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='cleaner'))
        
    if request.POST and request.FILES:
        print("it came")
        forms_valid = True
        print("ygytgf",forms_valid)
        for form in formsets:
            if f'{form.prefix}-submit' not in request.POST:
                continue
            if not form.is_valid():
                forms_valid = False
                print(f"Form {form.prefix} is not valid:")
                for field, errors in form.errors.items():
                    for error in errors:
                        print(f"Error in field {field}: {error}")
        if forms_valid:
            for form in formsets:
                if isinstance(form, CookingForm):
                    register_cook = form.save(commit=False)
                    register_cook.cook = staff
                    register_cook.save()
                elif isinstance(form, DriverForm):
                    register_driver = form.save(commit=False)
                    register_driver.driver = staff
                    register_driver.save()
                elif isinstance(form, GardenerForm):
                    register_gardener = form.save(commit=False)
                    register_gardener.gardener = staff
                    register_gardener.save()
                elif isinstance(form, ElderCareTakerForm):
                    register_elder_care_taker = form.save(commit=False)
                    register_elder_care_taker.elder_care_taker = staff
                    register_elder_care_taker.save()
                elif isinstance(form, NannyForm):
                    register_nanny = form.save(commit=False)
                    register_nanny.nanny = staff
                    register_nanny.save()
                elif isinstance(form, FullMaidForm):
                    register_full_maid = form.save(commit=False)
                    register_full_maid.full_maid = staff
                    register_full_maid.save()
                elif isinstance(form, CleanerForm):
                    register_cleaner = form.save(commit=False)
                    register_cleaner.cleaner = staff
                    register_cleaner.save()

            return redirect('staffapplicanthome', uid)
        else:
            print("forms not valid")
            for field, errors in form.errors.items():
                for error in errors:
                    print(f"Error in field {field}: {error}")
    
    return render(request, 'staff/staffapply2.html', {'formsets': formsets, 'uid': uid})
```

This is the forms.py

```
class FullMaidForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FullMaid
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['full_maid']
        enctype = 'multipart/form-data'
class CleanerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cleaner
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['cleaner']
        enctype = 'multipart/form-data'
```

This is models.py

```
class FullMaid(models.Model):
    full_maid=models.ForeignKey(StaffApplicantTable,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    experience=models.IntegerField()
    wages_expected=models.IntegerField()
    desc=models.TextField()
    
class Cleaner(models.Model):
    cleaner=models.ForeignKey(StaffApplicantTable,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    experience=models.IntegerField()
    wages_expected=models.IntegerField()
    desc=models.TextField()
```

The other forms are getting submitted..Only these two are creating problems...Please help me sort this out.

Comment: `request.POST` **->and<-** `request.FILES` ..maybe just make that an **or**

Comment: I didn't see this silly mistake. Thank you so much bro...I got cleared.